# Extracting rel with href

Tags: php, regex, expression

The following regular expression extracts all hrefs from a page with 'preg_match_all':

```
/\s+href\s*=\s*[\"\']?([^\s\"\']+)[\"\'\s]+/ims
```

IF there is a 'rel' attribute in the 'a' tag i would like to return that with the result. How do i modify the code at the top to include the 'rel' attribute(if present)?

UPDATE:
the following:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">Duis</a>
nirure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  href="http://example.com" 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://example.com
        )

)
```

i would like it to return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://example.com
        )

)
```

Comment: what would be the input and expected output

Comment: making an example :)

Comment: you can also use alternatives like HTML parsers `DOMDocument`

Comment: Your regex doesnot return `href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can optionally capture it using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$regex = '~<a\b(?=(?>[^>]*rel\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']+))?)[^>]*href=\s*["\']\s*\K[^"\']+~';
```

Add the `i (PCRE_CASELESS)` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) after closing [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) `~` to match *case insensitive*.

See further explanation and [example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bO1gB5/2) and [SO Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) maybe want to add `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag:

```
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($out);
```

Which gives a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://example.com
            [1] => nofollow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://example2.com
            [1] => nofollow
        )

)
```

See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/193369)

As others mentioned, regex is not the [perfect means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/3110638) for parsing html. Depends on what you're going to achieve and how the input looks / if it is your input and know what to expect.

Comment: the following returns: unknown modifier '['

Comment: @ThomasdeRoo of course, it was the regex only, see update and example at eval.in

Answer (score 1):

```
\s+href\s*=\s*[\"\']?(([^\s\"\']+)[\"\'\s]+rel="[^"]*")|\s+href\s*=\s*[\"\']?([^\s\"\']+)[\"\'\s]+
```

You can use this.This will give `rel` if it is there.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/4

Comment: @ThomasdeRoo what is to be escaped?